# How do I calculate monthly payments given a certain loan amount, APR, and loan term in years?

Tags: loans

I have a homework assignment to create a calculator that calculates a monthly payment, given a certain loan amount, APR, and loan term (in years). What is the formula I need to use?

Comment: Have you searched for "loan payment formula? I get many results that give the fairly simple formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following variables

```
s = principal
r = periodic rate
n = number of periods
d = periodic payment
```

*Standard loan equation*  - formula derived [by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1039800/119821)

[image: loan equation]

[image: repayment formula]

```
d = r s (1/((1 + r)^n - 1) + 1)
```

If your APR is quoted in the USA it will be a [nominal rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).  For a loan with monthly repayments and a "nominal APR *compounded monthly*" the periodic rate `r = APR/12`

E.g.

```
APR = 5% = 0.05
r = 0.05/12 = 0.00416667
```

If your APR is quoted in Europe it will be an [effective annual rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).  To convert to a periodic monthly rate `r = (1 + APR/100)^(1/12) - 1`

E.g.

```
APR = 5% = 0.05
r = (1 + 0.05)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00407412
```

See [Investopedia - Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities) for more insight into how this is calculated.

For example, the Investopedia loan illustration, with 5 annual payments and APR of 5% (nominal compounded annually is the same as effective annual rate.)

> Using the same example of five $1,000 payments made over a period of
> five years, here is how a present value calculation would look. It
> shows that $4,329.58, invested at 5% interest, would be sufficient to
> produce those five $1,000 payments.

[image]

```
s = 4329.58
r = 0.05
n = 5

d = r s (1/((1 + r)^n - 1) + 1) = 1000
```

Comment: Just to check my math. Given s=$4329.58, r=0.05/12  n = 5*12 = 60 months, then d = $81.70. Is that correct?

Comment: @moonman239 Hi, yes correct for a nominal APR compounded monthly.  The type of nominal rate should always be quoted, because 5% APR compounded quarterly is not the same as 5% compounded monthly, or daily.  The correct answer $81.70 compares OK to the ballpark estimate $1000/12 = $83.33, just as a rough check.